# Disable .htm in URL

Tags: asp.net, url

Greetings!

I am working on a ASP.net site, it uses MasterPage concept. All the content pages are using IFrame to display contents from .htm files. The session is maintained in MasterPages, after login. I want to protect my .htm pages to be directly opened. Hence, I want disable .htm pages to be disabled, if user opens from my site.

Below is the example, in case I am not able to clear my query.
My site have various folders Masterpage, pages, etc.
Every folder (except Masterpage folder) have .htm pages also along with Default.aspx, like pages folder have one Default.aspx and 1.htm, 2.htm.... and so on.
If user open, www.mysite.com/pages/Default.aspx, its fine. but if he tries to open www.mysite.com.pages/1.htm it should not be opened & get redirected to my Login Page (say login.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to protect the pages after login then the page you have to protect you need to check whether

> the session for the user who logged
>   in is set or not

if session is set then allow access otherwise redirect to login page.

for URL rewriting the helpful articles

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/02/26/tip-trick-url-rewriting-with-asp-net.aspx

Comment: The session is set, in .aspx pages but I want to disable user to open .htm pages